# Can T-SQL store ulong's?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, bigint, ulong

I want to store a C#.NET `ulong` into a T-SQL database. I don't see any provisions for doing this, as the SQL `bigint` has the same Min/Max values as a normal `long`.

Is there any way I can do this? Or is catching an `OverflowException` my only hope?

Comment: See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34036) which tells you to use `DECIMAL(20,0) CHECK (columnName >= 0 AND columnName <= 18446744073709551615)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should answer your question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/ff08c190-a981-4896-9542-3f64b95a84a2/

You would use BigInt, you just have to be careful in how you convert the signed type back into an unsigned type in C#

```
// This has not been tested
unchecked
{
    myUlong = myDataReader.GetInt64(...);
}
```

...

The other possibility is to use VarBinary with a length of 8, then convert the bytes to a ulong in C#

Comment: @Robert Harvey:  I posted a short example

Comment: Do you mean treating `long.MinValue` as `0` and `long.MaxValue` as `ulong.MaxValue`?

Comment: Is the behavior for the signed bit defined properly here? If you don't want to lose precision, you have to use the sign bit as the additional high-order bit in the ulong.  Will this do that?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: thats why it's unchecked.  High order bit doesnt matter to ulong, it just wants the 8 full bytes.

Comment: `bigint` cannot store `ulong` as that is basically `long`. `ulong` has higher range. `varbinary` is the right answer.

Comment: @Mrchief, it doesnt have anything to do with the range, it's the number of bits.  Notice the code above converts from unsigned to signed.

Comment: Well, try inserting 9223372036854775808 (long.Max + 1) in a bigint. You'll be greeted with a "Arithmetic overflow error". That's what I mean by range. That number is valid `ulong` but can't be stored in `bigint`. Makes sense?

Comment: @Mrchief, which is why you convert it to signed first.  9223372036854775808 converted to signed is -9223372036854775808, which inserts into a bigint field just fine.  You just have to remember to convert it again on the way back out of the database. Ulong.MaxValue (18446744073709551615), converted to signed, is -1, which also inserts into BigInt just fine ;)

Comment: I used `UInt64` as a variable's type and the type of the corresponding column in **DB** is `BIGINT`. It is showing the following **error:** `The parameter data type of UInt64 is invalid.` Can this be sorted out or I need to change `UInt64` to `Int64`?

Comment: @barnes: did you remember the "unchecked" code block?

Comment: No! I missed it. Thanks mate. :)

Answer (score 6):

I know it's not the same, but would this do:

```
select convert(decimal(38, 0), 12345678901234567890123456789012345678)
```

The maximum for an unsigned long seems to be 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 which is significantly less than this decimal can store. There might be issues converting, but I'm sure that a couple of wrapper functions in your application would sort it pretty quickly.

Comment: Good approach for accommodating the range of a ulong, however be aware that sql reports that decimal(38,0) takes up 17 bytes.

Comment: Are you saying it's oversize for the amount of data we want to store?

Comment: @Johnathan: I think so. `decimal(38,0)` is more than double the size of `bigint` (2.125 times, actually) . If space was an issue, I'd be a little concerned.

Comment: @Onion-Knight The [maximum value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4(v=VS.100).aspx) of an unsigned long is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615, meaning you only need `DECIMAL(20, 0)`. This takes 13 instead of 17 bytes. The advantage of `DECIMAL` over `BIGINT` is that it will preserve the semantic meaning of the numbers you are storing. Any other application, ETL, report, or human that looks at the numbers will understand them. From a data architect's perspective, that justifies the storage penalty. The `BIGINT`, on the other hand, will present negative numbers (i.e. lies) to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

For me Neil N's solution didn't work. Visual Studio kept complaining that I can't assign a `long` value to a `ulong` variable, no matter the `unchecked`.

What did work in the end was simply

```
ulong fileSize = (ulong)(long)reader["fileSize"];
```

(without`unchecked`).

In the SQLite DB the value is stored as `long`, so very high values become negative and sorting them on SQL-side fails. But after getting the `ulong` values Linq can do its magic

```
items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.FileSize).ToList();
```